# Is there any way to retrieve the settings ran from fstab that were used at boot?

Tags: linux, backup, fstab

I suck at life and accidentally overwrote my fstab before making a backup by trying to

`chmod 777 /etc/fstab`

so I could edit and resave it via a text editor.

So my question is, since most of these settings are used at boot to set up various things like swap and such, is there a way to determine what was in my previous fstab as long as I haven't restarted my server?

I've thrown a backup of a default in there, but I need this as apparently there were some customized things in the lost fstab file.

Cheers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at your `/etc/mtab`, `/proc/swaps` files and look at the output of `mount`.  This should give you enough information to re-construct your fstab.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the above answer (which is valid):

If your system happens to be using LVM snapshots, then you can mount the snapshot volume and recover the file from there.

If you merely *deleted* the file, rather than overwriting it, you can recover the text contents of the file as follows:

1. shut down to single user
2. grep on a known mount point (such as the boot partition sda1) on the partition that /etc/fstab resides: grep -a -B30 -A30 -i sda1 /dev/sda2

This greps for text string "sda1" on all data on the /dev/sda2 partition, and grabs 30 lines of text before and after, as well, which should be sufficient to cover a normal sized /etc/fstab.